# What ports are required to open for Aws S3 to work

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, firewall

I am using amazon SDK for S3 to upload and download files from my server. The server is behind a firewall where 80,443 ports are open for incoming traffic. But S3 doesn't work until I open ports between 55000-and 65535. Can you please help me find the right port that S3 .NET SDK requires to work?

**Edit**
I am not using AWS servers. It's a dedicated server from another company.

Comment: Is the code running on an Amazon EC2 instance, or your own computer on the Internet? When you "open ports", are you opening them for Inbound or Outbound connections?

Comment: The code is running out of Aws services. I have a dedicated root server from a third party. I am opening port in inbound rules.

Comment: If you are making API calls from the Internet to Amazon S3, it should simply use port 443 as the **destination** port. Your **source** port will, of course, be a random port in that high range. Traditionally, you would **open ALL outbound ports** since you can usually trust your own server.